# SQL how to increase or decrease x++ x-- in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a huge data i want to increase and decrease them with `x++` and `x--`
i can do this with php
but i can not with sql
is there any way to do this task please

**example**

i have a code `19` in my database this code is for some products the similar products has the same code but with increase or decrease
`18  17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10`
like this
i can save this data into database but i have more then 2000 codes

is there any way to make like this

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE code='19' OR 
x++
```

i need to get all data without save them all
i hope you understand my problem

Comment: What should be x in your query?

Comment: I know language (English) is hard, but this question is pretty unclear about what you are trying to do.  Please add some information on what you have, what needs to be done, and what the desired final situation is like.

Comment: Please add table definition, sample data in tabular form as text to the question. A couple of worked examples would also help for example if where code = 16 what would x++ or x-- look like and why

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean greater than or equal `>=` or less than or equal `<=`?

For example you want to select the data below and equal to 19 then your query should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE code >= 19;
```

Output : `19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24` and so on..

And if you want to select the code greater than 19 then your query should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE code <= 19;
```

Output : `1 to 19`..

And to be specific of the column you want to select just indicate the column name instead of using `*`.

```
SELECT code FROM items WHERE code >= 19;
```

or

```
SELECT code FROM items WHERE code <= 19;
```